# Angular AOT Compiler - Which folder does it save compiled too?

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 8 and would like to serve the live compile files to a server so I can test it on my ipad through my local wifi network. Only thing I am struggling to find which folder to point my server to serve for the AOT live compiler files? Appreciate the help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Running the command: `ng build --prod --aot` from your project's top directory will create this directory `dist/[name from package.json]` with all of your website's files.  I prefer to manually move these files to `/var/www/html` for apache or `C:/inetpub/wwwroot` in Windows.